# Render image in SpringMvc

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I want my image show up in *receipt_failure.html* via such thymeleaf expression :

```
<img th:src="@{/src/main/resources/images/icons-alert-circle.png}" />
```

Image itself has settled in such SpringMVC folder structure:

[image]

I do not get where issue comes from because seems like I keep path structure but I am getting such error on my local environment

[image: environment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved */images* folder into */static* folder then fix html like this:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/icons-alert-circle.png}" />
```

and issue has been fixed